# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed on while(Reader.read()). why?

Tags: c#

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NSIC;Initial Catalog=Dev;User ID=sa;Password=123456"))
{
    // SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Employee", connection);
    connection.Open();
    //adapter.Fill(ds);
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee", connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            while (reader.Read()) //Error is here
            {
                var table = new DataTable();
                table.Load(reader);
                ds.Tables.Add(table);
            }
        }
    }
}
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

I am trying to retrieve data from data sql server.but error on `while(Reader.read())`.

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed on
>   while(Reader.read()).

why?

Comment: try `ExecuteReader` without `CloseConnection` `CommandBehavior`. Like this `command.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: You reader is probably null.  Test for null before the while loop.

Comment: Why are you creating one datatable per row? Try simply removing the while-part, leaving the 3 lines inside.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're using [DataTable.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx) inside the while-loop.

The while-loop basically says "While there are more rows", and then you call `DataTable.Load` that loads *all* the rows, and then go back to check for more.

Instead you can simply remove the `while` loop altogether:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(reader);
    ds.Tables.Add(table);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` is messing with your reader.

Try using it like below;

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NSIC;Initial Catalog=Dev;User ID=sa;Password=123456"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               var table = new DataTable();
               table.Load(reader);
               ds.Tables.Add(table);
            }
        }
    }
```